# Symbolic simplifications in radare2

Tags: radare2

Let's have a look to this assembly code in radare2:

```
xxxxxxx  mov rax,rbx
xxxxxxx  add rax,rax
xxxxxxx  add rax,rbx
xxxxxxx  shl rax,2
yyyyyyy  nop
```

Is there a way to ask radare2 to evaluate `rax` value at `yyyyyy` address ?

I want radare2 to say: `rax=rbx*6`

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. What do you mean by "evaluate rax at address"? Just set a breakpoint and look at the register.

Comment: I do not want to run the program. I want to select lines and ask radare2 to compute a formula which represents how rax is calculated

Comment: Use the decompiler to see such transformation. See [r2ghidra](https://github.com/radareorg/r2ghidra). And use the `pdg` command.

Answer (score 1):

This looks a lot like symbolic execution. For concrete values this is already supported.

```
[0x006000b0]> e asm.emu=true
[0x006000b0]> pdf
            ;-- section..shellcode:
            ;-- rip:
┌ (fcn) entry0 23
│   entry0 ();
│           0x006000b0      48c7c3444342.  mov rbx, 0x41424344         ; 'DCBA' ; [01] -rwx section size 22 named .shellcode ; rbx=0x41424344
│           0x006000b7      4889d8         mov rax, rbx                ; rax=0x41424344
│           0x006000ba      4801c0         add rax, rax                ; '#' ; rax=0x82848688 ; of=0x0 ; sf=0x0 ; zf=0x0 ; cf=0x0 ; pf=0x1
│           0x006000bd      4801d8         add rax, rbx                ; '%' ; rax=0xc3c6c9cc ; of=0x0 ; sf=0x0 ; zf=0x0 ; cf=0x0 ; pf=0x1
│           0x006000c0      48c1e002       shl rax, 2                  ; rax=0x30f1b2730 ; zf=0x0 ; pf=0x1 ; sf=0x0
```

ESIL is not that powerful for static analysis as such. I don't think there exists a plugin which does this. There are r2 plugins like [rune](https://github.com/radareorg/rune) which have some symbolic execution features, you can give them a try.

A rather simple option for you to do this is to use [miasm](https://github.com/cea-sec/miasm), which can simplify symbolic execution of a basic block and print expressions/relations. An option is to use [r2m2](https://github.com/guedou/r2m2) for the same (Maijin from r2 told me this).

```
from miasm2.analysis.binary import Container
from miasm2.analysis.machine import Machine
import sys

with open("/tmp/resenm", "rb") as fdesc:
    cont = Container.from_stream(fdesc)

default_addr = cont.entry_point
bs = cont.bin_stream

machine = Machine(cont.arch)
mn, dis_engine = machine.mn, machine.dis_engine
ira, ir = machine.ira, machine.ir

mdis = dis_engine(bs, loc_db=cont.loc_db)

ir_arch = ir(mdis.loc_db)
ir_arch_a = ira(mdis.loc_db)

ircfg = ir_arch.new_ircfg()
ircfg_a = ir_arch_a.new_ircfg()

asmcfg = mdis.dis_multiblock(default_addr)
print len(asmcfg)
for block in asmcfg.blocks:
    ir_arch.add_asmblock_to_ircfg(block, ircfg)
    ir_arch_a.add_asmblock_to_ircfg(block, ircfg_a)

from miasm2.ir.symbexec import SymbolicExecutionEngine
from miasm2.arch.x86.regs import regs_init
from miasm2.expression.simplifications import expr_simp
from miasm2.expression.expression import ExprId

sb = SymbolicExecutionEngine(ir_arch_a, regs_init)

nxt_ad = sb.run_at(ircfg_a, default_addr)
print expr_simp(sb.symbols[ExprId("RAX",64)])
```

will print something like

```
1
(RBX_init + RBX_init + RBX_init) << 0x2
```

Interface this with radare2 hackishly with "!". As I am not so good with r2, I have posted this to r2 irc. Lets see if we get better options.